# Manipulate prefixes with round up digits in r

Tags: r

x is created based on various data. After that I use an `IF` statement in order to change x to specific values. See below for an example

```
x = 2500000
      chrs <- strsplit(format(x, scientific=12), split="")[[1]];
      rem <- chrs[seq(1,length(chrs)-6)];
      rem <- append(rem, "M");
```

This returns `2M`

The difference between 2.5M and 2M is way to big, therefore I would like to be this shown as 2.5M.

Whenever this given value would be between 2.1 and 2.9 I would like to have it shown like that. But when it is 2.0M I would like it to be 2M

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scales` package:

```
library(scales)
x = 2500000
label_number_si(accuracy=0.1)(x)
```

Output:

```
 "2.5M"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `round` and `paste0`:

```
paste0(round(2.5e6/1e6, 1), "M")
[1] "2.5M"

paste0(round(2e6 / 1e6, 1), "M")
[1] "2M"
```